# From string to datetime with or without millisecond

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a list of strings each of them represent a time with or without milliseconds, e.g.

`l = ['03:18:45.2345', '03:19:23']`

 And I want to convert each string into a datetime object. Now I'm running:

```
>>> l = ['03:18:45.2345', '03:19:23']
>>> for item in l:
...     print datetime.datetime.strptime(item, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
... 
1900-01-01 03:18:45.234500
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '03:19:23' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

Hence, the question is: How do I iterate the list converting each element in a `datetime` object?

The first thought is to have a `try..except..`:

```
try:
    print datetime.datetime.strptime(item, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
except:
    print datetime.datetime.strptime(item, "%H:%M:%S")
```

Is there any way to do that without catching the `ValueError`?

Comment: What's wrong with catching the ValueError?

Comment: In general there's nothing wrong. However, if you have the `strptime` in a more complicated statement, e.g. `return (..., strptime(), ..)` it is better - in my opinion and for the sake of readability to not have to `try: return..;except: return..;`.

Comment: Then refactor it out as a separate function?

Comment: I'll accept Eugene's answer because, in my opinion, it's the cleanest way to fix the issue and also because it's the nearest to what I was looking for. (I hoped there was some clever regex-ish way to fix..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l = ['03:18:45.2345', '03:19:23']
for item in l:
    time_format = "%H:%M:%S.%f" if '.' in item else "%H:%M:%S"
    print datetime.datetime.strptime(item, time_format)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are handling more complicated situation(the date string more complex). I recommend you to use [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) instead of the `datetime` module.

`dateutil.parser` offers a generic date/time string parser which is able to parse most known formats to represent a date and/or time.

The prototype of this function is: `parse(timestr)`(you don't have to specify the format yourself).

**DEMO**

```
>>> parse("2003-09-25T10:49:41")
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 10, 49, 41)

>>> parse("2003-09-25T10:49")
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 10, 49)
```

Fuzzy parsing:

```
>>> s = "Today is 25 of September of 2003, exactly " \
...     "at 10:49:41 with timezone -03:00."
>>> parse(s, fuzzy=True)
datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 10, 49, 41,
              tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -10800))
```

Answer (score 0):

`ValueError` approach is fine but if you want to avoid `try/except` here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime

for time_string in ['03:18:45.2345', '03:19:23']:
    time_string, dot, us = time_string.partition('.')
    d = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%H:%M:%S')
    if dot:
        d = d.replace(microsecond=datetime.strptime(us, '%f').microsecond)
    print(repr(d.time()))
```

#### Output

```
datetime.time(3, 18, 45, 234500)
datetime.time(3, 19, 23)
```